# Database changed by hand on EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a database which is generated by EF code first. My coworker added a column to this database by hand (not by using EF migrations). Then I added the column name to my entity to make it synchronized.  Now I remove another column using EF Code first migration. Would anything bad happen when I use update-database? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it. I think that is worked.

1. Remove properties from the model.
2. Run 'Enable-Migrations' in package manage console.
3. Next Run 'Add-Migration "MigrationsName"'. if any case it is showing 'The project  tesproject failed to build then build project again.
4. Now run 'Update-Database'